# The specified task executable "sh" could not be run. Permission denied

Tags: linux, angular, shell, .net-core

I am attempting to run a dotnet-core (2.0) Angular project in Linux Mint 18.  I take the following steps to generate the project and run:

1. dotnet new angular -o AngularTest
2. cd AngularTest
3. npm install
4. dotnet run

On the "dotnet run" step, I get the following result:

> /home/username/scratch/dotnet-core/AngularTest/AngularTest.csproj(20,3): warning MSB6003: The specified task executable "sh" could not be run. Permission denied
>
> /home/username/scratch/dotnet-core/AngularTest/AngularTest.csproj(23,3): error : Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE.
>
> The build failed. Please fix the build errors and run again.

The real problem seems to be the sh permission warning.  The Node.js error is only being reported because the sh step can't be completed.

I can't figure out what's causing the sh permission issue.  sh is in the path, and it (along with the dash executable it points to) has execute permissions for all.

I get the same warning/error when I try to run from Visual Studio Code.

I've published the project source here: https://github.com/jfcarr/angular-test-linux

Comment: I ran the same steps on a MacOS and it worked fine. Your error points to the command: node --version. Can you run that and paste the output? Or actually publish your whole solution on github so we can execute the steps on the same files.

Comment: The output of node --version is "v4.2.6".  When the project runs, it reports the "Node.js is required" error because it can't shell out to check it.

I'll get the solution into a github repo and publish the link.

Comment: I added a project link to the original description.

Comment: 23:43 $ npm install
~/git/angular-test-linux [master|✔]
23:44 $ dotnet run
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /Users/u/git/angular-test-linux
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. It worked. I'm on MacOS 10.12 and .NET Core CLI 2.0.0, Node v6.11.2. Maybe a Linux mint issue? Are you on version 17 or 18?

Comment: Interesting.  It definitely seems to be environment specific.  I'm on Mint 18.